# How to modify the column widths of a Word table using Perl?

Tags: perl, ms-word, win32ole

Using Perl with the Win32::OLE module I am attemping to insert a table into a Microsoft Word document and then modify the column widths. I can insert a table without any trouble, but modifying the column widths is proving more difficult. After creating a macro and trying to translate the VBA into Perl, here is what I have:

```
my $word = Win32::OLE->new('Word.Application', sub {$_[0]->Quit;});
my $doc = $word->Documents->Open('myfile.doc');

### Code to find and select a tag to replace with a table goes here ###

my $table = $doc->Tables->Add($word->Selection->Range, 4, 4);
$table->Columns(1)->{PreferredWidthType} = wdPreferredWidthPoints;
$table->Columns(1)->{PreferredWidth} = 200;
```

Unfortunately this gives a "Can't use an undefined value as a HASH reference" error on the final two lines. I've tried several other variations on this but none have worked, and Google hasn't helped either. I'd really appreciate an answer as to how to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest using `Data::Dumper` to print `$table -> Columns(1)` because that error implies that `Columns(1)` is undefined.

Comment: @Sobrique, Caveat: If you use Data::Dumper on OLE Objects *make sure* you set `$Data::Dumper::MaxDepth`--especially in dealing with Microsoft Application objects, which commonly have every single object pointing back to the Application object which contains everything. Win32::OLE does not, as a default, generate unique objects, and will simply use up your memory remaking the same Application object again, and again, and again.

Comment: You can also specify `_Unique` when loading the module: http://search.cpan.org/~jdb/Win32-OLE-0.1712/lib/Win32/OLE.pm#_Unique

Comment: @Sobrique: You are indeed correct that it is undefined, but this doesn't get me any closer to solving the problem unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error I found that this did the job:

```
$table->Rows(1)->Select;
$word->Selection->Columns(1)->{Width} = 200;
```

It was sufficient to resize just the columns on row 1, and this affected all other rows. It's easy when you know how!